# How to transfer dual boot system to new SSD

Tags: dual-boot, ssd, secure-boot

My Toshiba Satellite L650-1PR laptop has been warning me for the past 4 days that its hard drive (750GB, SATA, 5400rpm HDD) is about to crash 'in less than 24 hours'. So I'm thinking of replacing it with a 1TB SSD. If I remember correctly Secure Boot wasn't an issue yet when I bought it in 2011.
I have a dual boot, Windows 7 + Debian Linux, which I want to transfer to the new SSD using Clonezilla or something similar. Should I expect problems or is the Secure Boot thing related to the cpu (Intel® Core™ i5 CPU M 480 @ 2.67GHz × 4)  and/or BIOS?

Comment: Secure boot is related to UEFI which many vendors still call BIOS. Your system may be early UEFI as most i-series chips were on motherboards that supported UEFI. Windows 7 could boot in UEFI mode, but not with Secure Boot on and most were BIOS boot installs on MBR partitioned drives. I would suggest new Windows & Ubuntu installs and restore your data from your backups. Windows 7 is EoL. Windows in UEFI mode requires gpt partitioning which would erase a MBR(msdos) drive.

Comment: Secure boot is primarily based on the signatures of files files.  As long as you perform a low-level copy no signatures should change or be corrupted.

Comment: Windows 7 supports booting in EFI mode but its boot loader is **not** signed, so it cannot run with secure UEFI mode on. Most likely you have just a EFI boot mode without the secure bit. Clonezilla should work just fine as long as you copy the GPT as well (to preserve partitions UUIDs).